# If $g(n+1) = g(n) + g(n - 1)$, and $g(1) = g(4) = 1$, then what is $g(10)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fibonacci-numbers

Let $g$ be a function such that $g(n+1) = g(n) + g(n - 1)$ for all integers $n$. If $g(1) = g(4) = 1$, then what is $g(10)$?

Comment: *Hint*: What does $g(1)=g(4)=1$ tell you about $g(2),g(3)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g(4)=g(3)+g(2)=2g(2)+g(1)=1$$
Since $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=0$. From here, you can either solve the recursion or compute $g(10)$ directly. (In fact, this is just the Fibonacci sequence "shifted down" two terms)

Comment: +1 (more) for the *shifted down* analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(2), g(3) = b,c$ respectively.

Then 
$b + c = g(4) = 1.$
$g(1) + b = 1 + b = g(2) = c.$

Solve for the two equations in two unknowns.